# Get object extension from AccessibleObjectFromWindow?

Tags: .net, interop, accessibility, fileinfo

I managed to get the selected file in the current working folder from Windows Explorer using SystemAccessibleObject from http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/

I want to get the filename with extension but if you enable "Hide extensions for known file types" then there will be only the filename. I'm stuck on this step.

My code:

```
SystemAccessibleObject currentWorkingWindow = SystemAccessibleObject.FromWindow(new SystemWindow(GetForegroundWindow()), AccessibleObjectID.OBJID_WINDOW).Children.Where(c => c.RoleString.Equals("client")).FirstOrDefault();

            if (null != currentWorkingWindow)
            {
                SystemWindow addressBar = currentWorkingWindow.Window.AllDescendantWindows.Where(w => w.ClassName.Equals("ComboBox")).FirstOrDefault();

                if (null != addressBar)
                {
                    string addressBarContent = addressBar.Content.LongDescription;

                    Match m = Regex.Match(addressBarContent, "Address \\[push button\\]\\n[A-Z]: \\n[A-Z]: ([A-Z]:\\\\[^/:*?<>|\"\\r\\n\\t]+)");

                    if (null != m || null != m.Groups[1])
                    {
                        SystemWindow currentListView = currentWorkingWindow.Window.AllDescendantWindows.Where(w => w.ClassName.Equals("SysListView32")).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (null != currentListView)
                        {
                            SystemAccessibleObject currentListViewItems = SystemAccessibleObject.FromWindow(currentListView, AccessibleObjectID.OBJID_WINDOW).Children.Where(c => c.RoleString.Equals("list")).FirstOrDefault();

                            if (null != currentListViewItems)
                            {
                                SystemAccessibleObject[] selectedItems = currentListViewItems.SelectedObjects;

                                string currentWorkingFolderPath = m.Groups[1].Value;

                                if (0 != selectedItems.Count())
                                {
                                    string[] fileNames = currentListView.Content.PropertyList.Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        currentListView = null;
                    }

                    m = null;
                }

                addressBar = null;
            }

            currentWorkingWindow = null;
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out the perfect solution yet but using Clipboard is not a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about the SystemAccessibleObject but why not approach this from a different angle.  You know the directory and the file name without extension, so you could use the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) and "find" your file with extension.

```
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
  string[] matchedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(currentWorkingFolderPath, fileName+"*");
  etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur comment but it can't help me out. I want to use this function on the current working folder, not the pre-defined one.